# Different graph results for Integral of $ \frac{1}{x^2-8x+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I had to do the integral of $ \frac{1}{x^2-8x+1} $.

The approach I followed is in the following MIT [video](https://youtu.be/4wPyBkwsIfw), they didn't finish writing the final integral but I did. However, after checking the answer from Wolfram and Integral-Calculator.com I get results that look a little bit different in a graph. Is my result wrong? How can the graphs be so different even between the answer of Wolfram and Integral-Calculator.com?

I graphed them all in Desmos as well: desmos.com/calculator/fftyt801sf

### My result using the approach from MIT

$$ -\frac{\sqrt{15}}{15}\cdot\ln\left(\left|\frac{x-4+\sqrt{15}}{\sqrt{\left(x-4\right)^{2}-15}}\right|\right) + C $$

[image]

### [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%201%2F%28x%5E2-8x%2B1%29)

[image]

### [Integral Calculator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=1%2F%28x%5E2-8x%2B1%29)

[image]

Comment: when you plot what value of $C$ you assume?

Comment: @Bayesianguy $ C = 0 $

Comment: let me get it... You plot differents results ?

Comment: The different results from each website for the same integral

Comment: Ok, first I think the plots between Wolfram and Integral calculator are the same...

Comment: Maybe they are plotting the complex values or something... Let me check it for a while

Comment: I graphed in a Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fftyt801sf. They share some features but they are definitely different, each one seems to reach a different maximum height

Comment: Does partial fractions work in this case?

Comment: Antiderivatives behave strangely for functions that don't have connected domains. You might find this video about the antiderivative of 1/x: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjQm5gMPMZI to provide some insight.

Comment: The only discrepancy I see is that the green graph, which basically combines the red and blue graphs, looks truncated in its spike just to the right of $0$. Is that what you are asking about?

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
x^2-8x+1=(x-4)^2-15=(x-4-\sqrt{15})(x-4+\sqrt{15})
$$
we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{x^2-8x+1}&=&\frac{1}{(x-4-\sqrt{15})(x-4+\sqrt{15})}\cr
&=&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{15}}\left(\frac{1}{x-4-\sqrt{15}}-\frac{1}{x-4+\sqrt{15}}\right).
\end{eqnarray}

It follows that

\begin{eqnarray}
\int \frac{1}{x^2-8x+1}\,dx&=&
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{15}}\int \left(\frac{1}{x-4-\sqrt{15}}-\frac{1}{x-4+\sqrt{15}}\right)\, dx\cr
&=&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{15}}\left(\ln|x-4-\sqrt{15}|-ln|x-4+\sqrt{15}|\right)+C\cr
&=&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{15}}\ln\left|\frac{x-4-\sqrt{15}}{x-4+\sqrt{15}}\right|+C
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

These all equal one annother:

$\ln \frac {|x-4 + \sqrt {15}|}{\sqrt{|(x-4)^2 - 15}} = \ln \frac {|x-4 + \sqrt {15}|}{\sqrt{|x-4 - \sqrt{15}||x-4 + \sqrt {15}}} = \ln\sqrt {\left|\frac {x-4 + \sqrt{15}}{x-4 -\sqrt{15}}\right|} = \frac 12 \ln \left|\frac {x-4 + \sqrt{15}}{x-4 -\sqrt{15}}\right| = \frac 12 (\ln|x-4+\sqrt 15| - \ln |x-4-\sqrt{15}|)$

A little simplification and you should be able to get between one result and the other.